# Twitter Followers profile scan

Tags: twitter

I want to scan profile data of followers.
My goal is to get followers numbers having Less then 20 twits or  10 followers.
I know how to get followers profile data.

Now, problem is suppose a profile have 1,00,000 Followers, than its a very big task to fatch all the profile data and identify profile having Less then 20 twits or  10 followers. And i need to make 1,00,000 twitter api calls, I this is not good idea.

Example : http://twitblock.org/

Is there any way to solve this ?

Thanks In advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) get his followers `followers/ids`  up to 5000 in single request, that's at at at least 20 requests (21 or 22 just to be safe)

b) get info on each follower `users/lookup` up to 100 in single request, that's 1000 requests

Given you can make no more than 350 requests per hour, per oAuth account you will need to use oAuth credentials of multiple authenticated users (3 users to be exact).